Java heap space out-of-memory issue
I'm having trouble with downloading a large csv file in Java with -Xmx200m. The app must process 20 million elements without OutOfMemoryError. Streaming and batch size reduction haven't helped. How can I handle this within 200MB???
Here are the exact error messages I'm encountering:
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-nio-8080-Poller"
Exception in thread "mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup"
Exception in thread "Catalina-utility-1"
Exception in thread "Catalina-utility-2"
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]

Importing: I'm importing a large CSV file for processing and storing in a database. File size: The file is ~1.5 GB with about 20 million rows, each having 9 fields. Processing: Data is validated, transformed into Person objects, and batch inserted into a database. Streaming: Using BufferedReader to process the file line-by-line with Java Streams API. Batch size: Reduced to 20 records per batch but still hitting OutOfMemoryError. JVM: Running with -Xmx200m memory limit.
    @Transactional
public void processCsvFile(Path pathToFile, int processId) {
    int batchSize = 40;
    List<Person> batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
    AtomicInteger processedRows = new AtomicInteger();

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    try (Stream<PersonDto> personDtoStream = csvFileReaderService.readCsvFile(pathToFile)) {
        personDtoStream.forEach(personDto -> {
            try {
                personValidationService.validatePersonDto(personDto);
                Person person = mappingFacade.mapToPerson(personDto);
                batch.add(person);

                if (batch.size() == batchSize) {
                    personBatchService.saveBatch(batch);
                    batch.clear();
                    System.gc();
                }
                processedRows.getAndIncrement();
                if (processedRows.get() % 100000 == 0) {
                    processStatusService.updateProcessedRows(processId, processedRows.get());
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                log.error("Error processing CSV data: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                processStatusService.updateStatus(processId, ProcessStatusEnum.FAILED, processedRows.get(), e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        });
        if (!batch.isEmpty()) {
            personBatchService.saveBatch(batch);
        }

public class CsvFileReaderService {
private final PersonParserRegistry parserRegistry;
@Transactional
public Stream<PersonDto> readCsvFile(Path pathToFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile);
    return bufferedReader.lines().skip(1)
            .map(this::parseCsvToPersonDto)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull);
}

private PersonDto parseCsvToPersonDto(String line) {
    try {
        String[] personProperties = line.split(",");
        if (personProperties.length < 9) {
            log.warn("Invalid CSV data format: Expected at least 9 fields, but got {}", personProperties.length);
            return null;
        }

        String type = personProperties[0].trim();
        PersonParser parser = parserRegistry.findParser(type);
        if (parser == null) {
            log.warn("No parser found for type: {}", type);
            return null;
        }

        log.debug("Parsing line: {}", line);
        return parser.parse(personProperties);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error parsing CSV line: {} - {}", line, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

}

It's very hard to offer constructive advice without know what "importing" means in this context, or "large" or "process" or "elements" or "streaming" or "batch size."

Hi, thanks for your response. Here’s more detail:
Importing: I'm importing a large CSV file for processing and storing in a database.
File size: The file is ~1.5 GB with about 20 million rows, each having 9 fields.
Processing: Data is validated, transformed into Person objects, and batch inserted into a database.
Streaming: Using BufferedReader to process the file line-by-line with Java Streams API.
Batch size: Reduced to 20 records per batch but still hitting OutOfMemoryError.
JVM: Running with -Xmx200m memory limit.

Please [edit] your post to include these details. Some representative code would be helpful too.

Are you using a library for CSV parsing or doing it by hand?

Added some code check it if you can

What is csvFileReaderService?

CsvFileReaderService reads a CSV file and produces a stream of PersonDto objects. It uses BufferedReader to process the file line-by-line, skipping the header. Each line is parsed by parseCsvToPersonDto, which splits the line into fields and checks for at least 9 fields. It uses PersonParser from PersonParserRegistry to convert fields into a PersonDto. Invalid lines or missing parsers are logged and result in null. This service supports efficient processing of large files with error handling via logging.

Without the source of csvFileReaderService and without info about where the OOME occurs, I'm not sure we can help you any more than you yourself can: You're hitting all the bells and whistles here, you're attempting to 'stream' it in the sense that when you process line 50,000, line 1 shouldn't be in memory anymore, and everything you've mentioned suggests that's how it it set up. Thus, there's an oversight or bug in stuff you haven't shown, and thus, we can't help.

Added csvFileReaderService, and the error appears immediately, about 3 seconds after starting the import.

I don't see any obvious issues. Is it possible you have a memory leak in saveBatch()?

I don't think there are memory leaks in saveBatch(). However, I'm seeing multiple OutOfMemoryError exceptions in various threads:
http-nio-8080-Poller
JFR Periodic Tasks
mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup
Catalina-utility-1
File Watcher
RMI TCP Connection(idle)
Catalina-utility-2

Please include your exact error message. You may not think it contains anything important, but a user with more knowledge on this would likely disagree.

Capture a heap dump at the error and analyze it with a tool like Eclipse MAT or VisualVM. We don't know what is in your application's memory to help.

I cant send capture of heap dump i am new in this platform

You have to analyze the heap dump yourself. Also using System.gc() is a code smell.

There are lots of Q&As, tutorials, articles, etc on how to diagnose and fix memory leaks.  (Google it.)  But the first step to recovery is acceptance.

200M is a very small heap. You may actually run out of memory even if everything is correct as the working set (without your huge file) is too large. If at all possible, see if you can make it work with 1024M or 2048M before you spend too much time searching for bugs.

try removing the @transactional? It's going to try to commit all the records in a single transaction, which won't fit in 200mb

Nearly identical Question was posted again next day: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78845734/642706

It looks like you are getting an error message in the readCsvFile method.
You load all the strings into memory and then use batch processing.
I see 2 ways to solve your problem.

Closing BufferedReader after fulling batch.
Use NIO.

